# Oracle 12.1 string literal on varchar2 with trailing space

Tags: oracle

I'm having a very specific issue with Oracle 12.1 concerning the handling of string literal ending with space in SQL `WHERE` clause applied on a `VARCHAR2(2500)` column (named 'NOTES').

As I need Case-and-Accent-Insensitive string comparison, I alter the `NLS_COMP` and `NLS_SORT` in a Logon Database trigger:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP='LINGUISTIC';  
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT='BINARY_AI';
```

Then, if i try this (*notice the ' ' space at the end of 'cholera', it is needed as the space is present in the table data, and I can't change it as I only have read-only access to the table*):

```
SELECT NOTES FROM DECCODESIDC WHERE NOTES='cholera ';
```

So far, so good, it returns the only row matching the criteria (*'Choléra '*)

But if i create a View based on the table, and I apply the same criteria, it doesn't return anything:

```
SELECT NOTES FROM (SELECT NOTES FROM DECCODESIDC) WHERE NOTES='cholera ';
```

I noticed that the `explain plan` is different between the two queries

Here is the first query explain plan:

[image: first query explain plan]
Notice the 6 last digits of `HEXTORAW` : `61 20 00   -> 61='a', 20=' ' *(space)*, 00=end`

And the second one:

[image: second query explain plan]
Notice the 6 last digits of `HEXTORAW` : `72 61 00   -> 72='r', 61='a', 00=end`

As we can see, the `HEXTORAW` function automatically added by Oracle remove the trailing space in the second query, but not in the first...

I'm aware that string literals are considered as `CHAR` by Oracle and are subject to space padding, but in this case the string literal is compared against a `VARCHAR2` type column... and it doesn't explain why the execution plans are differents ...

Am I missing something or is it a bug in Oracle?

Benoit

ps: the fact is that I don't write such queries by hand, but rely on Entity Framework with Oracle Managed Drivers, so I don't have so much options concerning query rewriting :(

ps2: As a temporary workaround, I added a call to the `TRIM` oracle function on every `VARCHAR2` column in my View, but it is suboptimal in term of performance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone facing the same problem: I applied patch bundle 12.1.0.2.170117 and everything seems to be ok now... :/

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you explicity cast the string character to VARCHAR2 as in 
... = CAST('yourstring' AS VARCHAR2). Not a solution, just something else to understand.

Frank

Comment: Sorry, I did not mentioned that during my tests, I tried to manually cast the string literal to a VARCHAR2, and that it works on both queries.
Unfortunately, Entity Framework is used and it creates the SQL with string literals... :/